# How do I get the color values ​of the indices in the array?

Tags: android, xml, cardview

In androidx version I want to programmatically add the background color of cardview. But I can't do it. Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setCardBackgroundColor (int)' gives a null object reference error. I couldn't figure it out.

Could you help?
Thank you

```
    CardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.crd);

    int colorArray[] = {R.color.colorCategory1, R.color.colorCategory12,R.color.colorCategory3, R.color.colorCategory4,
            R.color.colorCategory5, R.color.colorCategory6,        R.color.colorCategory7, R.color.colorCategory8,
            R.color.colorCategory9, R.color.colorCategory10, R.color.colorCategory11, R.color.colorCategory12,
            R.color.colorCategory13, R.color.colorCategory14, R.color.colorCategory15,};


    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(colorArray[0]);
```

Comment: well, how can i actual color ?

Comment: try my answer i put up

Comment: i actually can't recreate your problem, i thought it was related to your array declaration but it all works for me, hopefully someone else can help you out

Comment: incompatible types.
Required: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
Found: int


I clicked the error bubble. it was writing error

Comment: where is your cardView? can you put up the xml file also?